# c++ lambda function that converts Eigen::VectorXd to Eigen::MatrixXd

Tags: c++, lambda, eigen

I need a lambda function that converts an `Eigen::VectorXd` to a `Eigen::MatrixXd` and unfortunately it doesn't work when I try to pass by const reference. Why can't I do this? Any workarounds?

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

typedef Eigen::Matrix< double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1              > Vec; 
typedef Eigen::Matrix< double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic > Mat;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Vec v (3);
    v(0) = 1.0;
    v(1) = 2.0;
    v(2) = 3.0;


    auto lambda = [](Vec vec) {return Eigen::Map<Mat>(vec.data(), vec.size(), 1);};
    Mat m = lambda(v);

    std::cout << m(0,0) << "\n";
    std::cout << m(1,0) << "\n";
    std::cout << m(2,0) << "\n";

    // does not work
    auto lambda2 = [](const Vec& vec) {return Eigen::Map<Mat>(vec.data(), vec.size(), 1);};

    return 0; }
```

The error message is `error: invalid conversion from 'const Scalar*  {aka const double*}' to 'Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >::PointerArgType {aka double*}' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: The compiler tells you that you are trying to convert something that is constant (`const Scalar*`) to non constant. I don't have the `Eigen` header so I'm taking a guess here saying that `Matrix`'s constructor does not like that `vec.data()` is const

Comment: Try adding `typedef Eigen::Matrix< const double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic > CMat;` and see if  `auto lambda2 = [](const Vec& vec) {return Eigen::Map<CMat>(vec.data(), vec.size(), 1);};` compiles

Comment: @ZivS no that doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: This works: `auto lambda2 = [](const Vec& vec) { return vec.array().matrix();};` but the return type is not `Mat` because I can't push it onto a `std::vector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the const case, you must construct a `Map<const TYPE>`:

```
auto lambda2 = [](const Vec& vec) {return Eigen::Map<const Mat>(vec.data(), vec.size(), 1);};
```

Or let the static function `Matrix::Map` does the right job for you:

```
auto lambda2 = [](const Vec& vec) {return Mat::Map(vec.data(), vec.size(), 1);};
```